# "I sat in the kitchen sipping my coffee" AND "… and I was sipping my coffee"

Tags: terminology, syntax

> "I sat in the kitchen sipping my coffee"
> "I sat in the kitchen and I was sipping my coffee"

These two sentences are the same meaning, but what type of grammar are between these two sentences?

Answer (score 0):

> I sat in the kitchen sipping my coffee.

> I sat in the kitchen and I was sipping my coffee.

Edit

The two sentences are of different constructions. The second is an unnecessarily complicated way of saying the first one.

The first sentence has *I sat in the kitchen* as the *main* clause; *sipping my coffee* is a gerund-participle phrase (or clause) describing the manner of sitting.

The second sentence has two *equal* clauses joined by the conjunction *and*.  I would add a comma:

> I sat in the kitchen, and I was sipping my coffee.

Comment: I would say they had different constructions rather than different meanings. The second is an unnecessarily complicated way of saying the first one.

Comment: Thx, Kate.  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *I **was sitting** in the kitchen (and) **sipping** my coffee*

This is in the past continuous, the two actions were both in progress at a specific point in the past.

The OP's first sentence:

> I **sat** in the kitchen [while/and I was] **sipping** my coffee.

The first verb is in the simple past, and suggests a more enduring action than the second, *sipping*, which is in the p[resent participle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/present-participle). In this example, the conjunction (*while* OR *and*), the subject (I), and the auxiliary *be* (was) have been omitted. Ellipsis is used when predictable words are non-essential to meaning.

Comment: I recognise your user Mari-Lou so I trust it is right but I don't understand it, I am a native UK speaker.

Comment: I think it is that the 2 quoted sentences aren't the original sentences from the question, did you edit after answering?

Comment: @WendyG I copied the 1st sentence but added in the square brackets “I sat in the kitchen [*while* OR  *and*] sipping my coffee”

Comment: and: "I was sitting in the kitchen (and) sipping my coffee"

Comment: @WendyG  That's my example which illustrates how the past continuous is structured. From there we have the OP's "we sat" (simple past), and "sipping coffee" (present participle). The OP's 2nd sentence is just a longer version of their first– "and I was".